# Como concatenar filtros con combineLatest en Angular

Tags: angular

con la siguiente funcion logro filtrar solo por un campo input que es el nombre de producto:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {

   this.articulosFiltrado$ = combineLatest(
     this.apiArticulo.getArticulos(),
     this.nombreProducto.valueChanges.pipe(
       startWith(''),
       debounceTime(300)
     ),
     this.categoriaSelect.valueChanges.pipe(
       startWith(''),
       debounceTime(300)
     ),
   ).pipe(
     map(([list, name]) => {
       let nameTerm: string = name.trim().toLowerCase();
       
       const completeList: articulo[] = [...list.data];
       let filteredByName: articulo[] = [];
      
       filteredByName = completeList.filter(item => {
         if (name === '') return true;
         return item.nombreProducto.toLowerCase().includes(nameTerm);
         
       }).concat()
       return filteredByName
      
     }),
    
  
     
     tap(res => {
       this.productsDataSource.data = res;
     })
   )
}
```

el caso es que quiero usar combineLatest para utilizar varios filtros a la vez sobre la tabla de articulos. Ademas del input nombre de producto de arriba tengo un mat select de categoria, pero no logro unificar ambos:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.someRef.focus();
    this.articulosFiltrado$ = combineLatest(
      this.apiArticulo.getArticulos(),
      this.nombreProducto.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        debounceTime(300)
      ),
      this.categoriaSelect.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        debounceTime(300)
      ),
    ).pipe(
      map(([list, name]) => {
        let nameTerm: string = name.trim().toLowerCase();
        
        const completeList: articulo[] = [...list.data];
        let filteredByName: articulo[] = [];
       
        filteredByName = completeList.filter(item => {
          if (name === '') return true;
          return item.NombreProducto.toLowerCase().includes(nameTerm);
          
        }).concat()
        let idC: number =  this.categoriaSelect.value;
  
        let filteredbyCategory: articulo[] = [];
        filteredbyCategory = completeList.filter(item => {
        
          return item.Id_categoria==idC;
          
        }).concat()
  
        return filteredbyCategory
   
       
      }),
     
   
      
      tap(res => {
        this.productsDataSource.data = res;
      })
    )
}
```

es decir si devuelvo filteredbyCategory solo filtra por categoria, y sino solo por nombre, no se que me esta faltando hacer en el codigo.

Edito: asi quedo mi codigo actual:

```
this.articulosFiltrado$ = combineLatest(
      this.apiArticulo.getArticulos(),
      this.nombreProducto.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        debounceTime(300)
      ),
      this.categoriaSelect.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        debounceTime(300)
      ),
    ).pipe(
      map(([list, name]) => {
        let nameTerm: string = name.trim().toLowerCase();
        
        const completeList: articulo[] = [...list.data];
        let filteredByName: articulo[] = [];
       
        filteredByName = completeList.filter(item => {
          if (name === '') return true;
          return item.NombreProducto.toLowerCase().includes(nameTerm);
          
        }).concat()
        let idC: number =  this.categoriaSelect.value;
  
        let filteredbyCategory: articulo[] = [];
        filteredbyCategory = filteredByName.filter(item => {
         
          return item.Id_categoria===idC;
          
        }).concat()
  
        return filteredbyCategory
   
       
      }),
     
   
      
      tap(res => {
        this.productsDataSource.data = res;
      })
    )
```

Como veran filteredByCategory que es el filtro de categoria es el array resultante de filtrar el array completo por el nombre, osea es un filtro sobre otro filtro.
Pero la tabla aparece vacia y debo seleccionar una categoria para filtrar por nombre.

Comment: En vez de usar la lista completa para filtrar por categoría, usa la lista previamente filtrada por nombre y aplícale el segundo filtro a esta.

Comment: Te suscribes al valuechanges de categoría en el combinelatest pero dentro de la suscripción obtienes el valor con `this.categoriaSelect.value` y además de eso, a la suscripción le pasas solo un array con dos valores, cuando en el combinelatest tienes tres? Veo cosas raras ahí.

Comment: @akotech funciono pero se inicia con la tabla vacía, tengo que seleccionar una categoría para que aparezcan registros, de que manera podria forzar que aparezcan de entrada todos los registros

Comment: CombineLatest se subscribe a a los distintos observables al mismo tiempo y los agrupa por el ultimo valor de cada uno me parece que ese es el motivo por el cual no aparecen de entrada los registros probaste con otro operador?

Comment: Que seria otro operador? Acabo de editar la pregunta con el codigo actual

Comment: @Caruso Para lo de la lista vacía, tienes que hacer lo mismo en el filtro de categorías que has hecho para el del nombre, devolver `true` si la categoría es un `string vacío`, o directamente ni filtrar. Una cosa que si tienes que corregir, es que en vez de obtener el valor de la categoría con `this.categoriaSelect.value`, añade en el array de la función del operador `map` un parámetro más para capturar el valor reactivo del tercer observable del `combineLatest`, quedándote algo así `map(([list, name, category]) => ...`

Comment: lo de la lista vacia se soluciono. El caso es que si se filtra por categoria y nombre pero espera que escriba el nombre

Answer (score 0):

Bueno tal como recomendo @akotech fui filtrando sobre el array filtrado y finalmente logre hacerlo con el siguiente codigo:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.someRef.focus();
    this.articulosFiltrado$ = combineLatest(
      this.apiArticulo.getArticulos(),
      this.nombreProducto.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        debounceTime(300)
      ),
      this.categoriaSelect.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        debounceTime(300)
      ),
      this.subCatSelect.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        debounceTime(300)
      ),
      this.nombre_marca.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        debounceTime(300)
      ),
    ).pipe(
      map(([list, name,category,subcategory,marca]) => {
        let nameTerm: string = name.trim().toLowerCase();
        
        const completeList: articulo[] = [...list.data];
        let filteredByName: articulo[];
       
        filteredByName = completeList.filter(item => {
          if (name === '') return true;
          return item.NombreProducto.toLowerCase().includes(nameTerm);
          
        }).concat()
        let idC: number =  category;
        if (category===''){idC=0}

        let filteredbyCategory: articulo[];
        filteredbyCategory = filteredByName.filter(item => {
          if (idC === 0) return true;
          return item.Id_categoria===idC;
          
        }).concat()
  
    
        let idS: number =  subcategory;
        if (subcategory===''){idS=0}

        let filteredbySubCategory: articulo[];
        filteredbySubCategory = filteredbyCategory.filter(item => {
          if (idS === 0) return true;
     
          return item.id_subcategoria===idS;
          
        }).concat()
  
        let idM: number =  marca;
        if (marca===''){idM=0}

        let filteredbyMarca: articulo[];
        filteredbyMarca = filteredbySubCategory.filter(item => {
          if (idM === 0) return true;
    
          return item.Id_marca===idM;
          
        }).concat()
  
       return filteredbyMarca;
      }),
     
   
      
      tap(res => {

        this.productsDataSource.data = res;
      })
    ) 
  
   this.categoriaSelect.valueChanges
    .subscribe(
      categoria => {

     
        //actualizo subcateogrias
        this.changeCategory(categoria);
        this.sc.focus();
        
      }
    )
  
  }
```

Como veran agregue la subcategoria y la marca. Funcionan todos jutos los filtros.